# Issue writing a function which determines if a date is in the future

Tags: python, date, datetime, boolean

I'm trying to to define a function called inTheFuture() that accepts a given year number, a month number, and a day number as 3 separate arguments. The function should return a Boolean value (True or False) to indicate whether the date (year, month, and day) parameters are in the future or not.

This is the error message I keep getting:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

I have tried converting float, string, int, and I'm just at a loss.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import datetime

year= input ("Enter Year: ");
month= int(input ("Enter Month: "));
day= int(input ("Enter Day: "));

def getTodaysDate():
    return datetime.datetime.today();
today = getTodaysDate();

def inTheFuture():
    ymd=(year,month,day)
    if float(ymd)>today:
        return true
    if float(ymd)<today:
        return false

inf = inTheFuture();
```

Comment: What do you expect `float` to return when passed a set of three numbers?

Comment: "I have tried converting float, string, int" - why? What are you trying to accomplish with the "conversion"? What error exactly did you get when you tried it without a conversion (I assume you tried this first, if you're trying all these other things in frustration)? What was your understanding of the problem?

Comment: a little bit of frustration and misleading information using google.  I understand I can't do that now.  I'm am in the right direction now thanks to you and Korem.  :)

Comment: btw the only reason I have ; is because my teacher is trying to make us do that since most languages require you to do so.  He just wants us to get in to the habit of using them.

Answer (score 1):

To work with dates (without time), you could use `datetime.date` class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import date

def in_future(date_to_test):
    """Whether *date_to_test* is in the future."""
    return date_to_test > date.today()

input_date = date(*map(int, input("Enter Year-Month-Day: ").split('-')))
print("Got {}. Is it in the future?".format(input_date))
print("yup" if in_future(input_date) else "nope")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as the error says: you attempt to compare `float(ymd)` to `today`, where `ymd` was assigned the tuple `(year, month, day)`. Exactly what result were you expecting? What do you think should happen when you pass `(year, month, day)` to `float`? It does not represent a `float` in any way I can think of.

But even then, your comparison makes no sense, because `today` is a `datetime.datetime` instance. What do you expect to happen when you compare a `float` to that? How is that supposed to work?

Compare apples to apples. If you want to know whether *the date and time represented by* a given `year`, `month` and `day` value is before a given `datetime.datetime` value, then use the `year`, `month` and `day` to create the kind of thing that *actually represents a date and time* - i.e., a `datetime.datetime` instance - the same kind of thing that you're comparing it *to*. Apples to apples.

The built-in `help`, as well as the online documentation, explain that this is a simple matter of passing those values, in the `year`/`month`/`day` order, to the `datetime.datetime` constructor:

```
day = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
if day > today: # etc.
```

Incidentally, there are multiple other issues with your program. You should not explicitly `raise SystemExit` yourself to abort a script (and it's generally better to let it just end naturally) - this is what `exit()` is for. You attempt to compute `inf` before you've actually verified the `year`, `month` and `day` values (but actually, there is no need to do this yourself; instead, the attempt to create a `datetime.datetime` with invalid values will raise a `ValueError` that you can detect for yourself). You have semicolons everywhere, which are unnecessary and a bad habit in Python. The boolean constants in Python are spelled `True` and `False`, with capital letters. Finally, your last line simply refers to `inf`, but doesn't *do anything* with it; this will not cause a value to be displayed. Within a script, you need to explicitly `print` things that you want to be output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a date to a float, a string or an int. `date` implements it's own comparisons. You need to convert your arguments to comply. This should work:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()

def inTheFuture(year, month, day):
    ymd=datetime.datetime(year,month,day).date()
    if ymd > today:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```