# Python Date game, Future/Past determination

Tags: python, date, time

#### Issue:

My program keeps telling me, no matter what, that my date is invalid.

#### Assignment:

The user will input a year, a month number (1-12), and a day number in that order. The program will 
determine if the date is in the future, or in the past. (If the date entered is today’s date, assume the date 
is in the past). A future date is a date that has not happened yet. If today is July 31st, August 1 of the 
same year is not in the past, just because the day (1) comes before today’s day (31).  For the input, if the user enters an invalid month, display an appropriate error message (like “Invalid 
Month”) and end the program. If the user enters an invalid day, display an appropriate error message
(like “Invalid Day”) and end the program. Assume 28 days in February. In other words, if the month is 
February and the day entered is 29, display the error message and end the program.

Remember:

```
Thirty days has September, 
April, June, and November
All the rest have 31
Except February, which has 28….
```

Define a function called `inTheFuture()` that accepts a given year number, a month number, and a 
day number as 3 separate arguments. The function should return a Boolean value (`True` or `False`) to 
indicate whether the date (year, month, and day) parameters are in the future or not. A `True` return 
occurs if the date is in the future; `False` if the date is in the past. It should not draw any images or text to 
the screen. It also should not ask the user for input. It just determines if a given date is in the future or 
not.

Find an image to represent the future, and an image to represent the past. Examples could include 
something like “The Jetson’s” for the future, and an old wagon for the past.If the date is in the future, display your future image in the middle of a canvas. If the date is in the past, 
display your past image in the middle of the canvas. At the top of the canvas, display “In the future” or 
“In the past”, whichever matches the image.

To find the current date, you may add this import and function to your code:

```
import datetime
def getTodaysDate():
    return datetime.datetime.today()
```

If you call this function somewhere in your code:

```
today = getTodaysDate()
```

Then you can use the year, month, and day member variables to obtain the current year, month, and 
day. For example:

```
print(today.month)
```

would output the current month.

Here is my program that I thought was finished. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't post assignments, try to ask a direct question in case you came across problems.

Comment: related: [Issue writing a function which determines if a date is in the future](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26453648/4279)

Answer (score 1):

This works for a date input like "24.12.2016". Change it to your needs in the line of strptime().

```
import datetime
from time import strptime

def date_in_the_future(date):
    datetime_string = strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y")
    d = datetime.datetime(datetime_string[0],datetime_string[1],datetime_string[2])
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = d - now
    diff = delta.days + 1
    if diff > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to use if,else, and elif. Check the code below:

```
import datetime
def getTodaysDate():
    return datetime.datetime.today();


today = getTodaysDate();
print(today)

                #def inTheFuture():



year= input ("Enter Year: ");
month= int(input ("Enter Month: "));
day= int(input ("Enter Day: "));

print"Correct, Your Day is:",day,"/",month,"/",year

if (month > 12):
    print("How many months in a year? Not as many as you think I suppose..")
    raise SystemExit
elif month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:
    if day > 31:
        print("What is a month where you are from?")
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        print"Correct, Your Day is:",day,"/",month,"/",year
elif (month == 2):
    if (day > 28):
        print("February only has so many days!")
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        print"Correct, Your Day is:",day,"/",month,"/",year
elif (month in [4,6,9,11]):
    if (day > 30):
        print("That day is not possible!")
    else:
        print"Correct, Your Day is:",day,"/",month,"/",year
```